# Word break pushes next li down

Tags: html, layout, css

I'm using `display: inline-block` to display my posts and whenever there's a long name, which needs to break on to a second line it pushes the next `li` down. I'm not exactly sure why it does this?

[image: When a word/line breaks it pushes li up]

Code:

```
<li>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="title"></div>
</li>
```

---

```
.li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.thumbnail {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.title {
    padding-top: 10px;
    max-width: 240px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'MavenProMedium';
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put `vertical-align: top` on your `li`s.

It happens because an inline-block element is, well, inline. It behaves in an inline way (besides also having block properties like "box-model"), so stuff like `line-height`, `vertical-align`, `text-align`, etc. have their effect on it.

Comment: I knew I was over looking something, got to make stupid mistakes to learn.

Comment: @Steven_Harris_ I have seen much stupider mistakes, I think this is nothing to feel ashamed about.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution I've found useful is to switch '`inline-block`' to '`inline-flex`' on the `li` elements.
I concede I don't really understand the difference, was just playing around in firebug with different values.
May not work on older browsers either, not sure.